# Не могу найти ошибку в слайдере

Tags: javascript, html, css

Перестали листиаться слайды

```js
var formSlider = document.querySelector('#form-slider'),
    divSlideArray = formSlider.querySelectorAll('.slide');

var divSliderArrows = document.querySelector('#slider-arrows'),
    divArrowLeft = divSliderArrows.querySelector('.arrow-left'),
    divArrowRight = divSliderArrows.querySelector('.arrow-right');

var currentSlide = 0;

divArrowLeft.addEventListener('click', function () {
    if (currentSlide > 0) {
        divArrowRight.style.setProperty('display', 'block', '');

        divSlideArray[currentSlide].style.setProperty('display', 'none', '');
        divSlideArray[--currentSlide].style.setProperty('display', 'block', '');

        if (currentSlide == 0)
            divArrowLeft.style.setProperty('display', 'none', '');
    }
});

divArrowRight.addEventListener('click', function () {
    if (currentSlide < divSlideArray.length - 1) {
        divArrowLeft.style.setProperty('display', 'block', '');

        divSlideArray[currentSlide].style.setProperty('display', 'none', '');
        divSlideArray[++currentSlide].style.setProperty('display', 'block', '');

        if (currentSlide == divSlideArray.length - 1)
            divArrowRight.style.setProperty('display', 'none', '');
    }

});
```

```css
input[type='radio'],
label {
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 22px;
    width: 22px;
    background: #494949;
}

.wrap-slider {
    position: relative;
}

#form-slider {
    width: auto;
}

#form-slider .slide {
    margin: 15% auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#form-slider .slide:first-child ~ .slide {
    display: none;
}

#slider-arrows [class^="arrow"] {
    
    user-select: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #4991e3;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 14px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    padding: 15px 60px;
    margin: 0 40px 40px;
    font-weight: 700;
}

#slider-arrows .arrow-left {
    display: none;
    left: 0;
}

#slider-arrows .arrow-right {
    float: right;
}

.slide {
    color: #fff;
    background: #494949;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

.heading {
    font-size: 28px;
    padding: 4% 6%;
    display: inline-flex;
}

.heading i {
    padding-right: 10px;
    color: #4991e3;
    font-size: 22px;
}

.num {
    font-size: 14px;
    padding-left: 100px;
}

.first {
    border-bottom: 5px solid #C9C9C9;
}

.radio {
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 22px;
    padding: 4% 6%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
 <div class="container">
     <div class="wrap-slider">
         <form id="form-slider" action="" method="post">
             <div class="slide">
              <div class="heading first">
               <i class="fa fa-file-text-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>

               <p>Пройди тест за 2 минуты, и узнай как удвоить поток клиентов в свой бизенс! Чек-лист по маркетингу стоимостью 20.000 р в подарок</p>

               <div class="num">1/6</div>
              </div>

              <div class="radio">
                  <p>Ваш бизнес продвигается с помощью сети интернет ?</p>
                  <p>
                   <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="answer1" value="answer1">
                   <label for="answer1">&nbsp&nbspДа</label>
                  </p>
                  <p>
                   <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="answer2" value="answer2">
                   <label for="answer2">&nbsp&nbspНет</label>
                  </p>
              </div>
     
     <div id="slider-arrows">
               <!--<div class="arrow-left">Назад</div>-->
               <div class="arrow-right">Вперед</div>
           </div>
             </div>

             <div class="slide">
                 <p>Вопрос 2</p>
                 <p>Ответ <input type="radio" name="radio2" value="answer1"></p>
                 <p>Ответ <input type="radio" name="radio2" value="answer2"></p>
                 <p>Ответ <input type="radio" name="radio2" value="answer3"></p>

     <div id="slider-arrows">
               <div class="arrow-left">Назад</div>
               <div class="arrow-right">Вперед</div>
           </div>
             </div>

             <div class="slide">
                 <p>Вопрос 3</p>
                 <p>Ответ <input type="radio" name="radio3" value="answer1"></p>
                 <p>Ответ <input type="radio" name="radio3" value="answer2"></p>
                 <p>Ответ <input type="radio" name="radio3" value="answer3"></p>
             </div>

             <div class="slide">
                 <p>Конец</p>
                 <p><input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Введите Ваше имя"></p>
                 <p><input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="Введите Ваш номер"></p>
                 <p><input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Введите Ваше мыло"></p>
                 <p><input type="submit" name="save"></p>
             </div>
         </form>
     </div>
 </div>
</section>
```

Comment: попробуйте заменить `divArrowLeft = divSliderArrows.querySelector('.arrow-left'),`  на `divArrowLeft = document.querySelector('.arrow-left'),`

Comment: @Дмытрык https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var formSlider = document.querySelector('#form-slider'),
    divSlideArray = document.querySelectorAll('.slide');

var divSliderArrows = document.querySelector('#slider-arrows'),
    divArrowLeft = document.querySelector('.arrow-left'),
    divArrowRight = document.querySelector('.arrow-right');

var currentSlide = 0;

divArrowLeft.addEventListener('click', function () {
    if (currentSlide > 0) {
        divArrowRight.style.setProperty('display', 'block', '');

        divSlideArray[currentSlide].style.setProperty('display', 'none', '');
        divSlideArray[--currentSlide].style.setProperty('display', 'block', '');

        if (currentSlide == 0)
            divArrowLeft.style.setProperty('display', 'none', '');
    }
});

divArrowRight.addEventListener('click', function () {
    if (currentSlide < divSlideArray.length - 1) {
        divArrowLeft.style.setProperty('display', 'block', '');

        divSlideArray[currentSlide].style.setProperty('display', 'none', '');
        divSlideArray[++currentSlide].style.setProperty('display', 'block', '');

        if (currentSlide == divSlideArray.length - 1)
            divArrowRight.style.setProperty('display', 'none', '');
    }

});
```

```css
input[type='radio'],
label {
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 22px;
    width: 22px;
    background: #494949;
}

.wrap-slider {
    position: relative;
}

#form-slider {
    width: auto;
}

#form-slider .slide {
    margin: 15% auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#form-slider .slide:first-child ~ .slide {
    display: none;
}

#slider-arrows [class^="arrow"] {
    
    user-select: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #4991e3;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 14px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    padding: 15px 60px;
    margin: 0 40px 40px;
    font-weight: 700;
}

#slider-arrows .arrow-left {
    display: none;
    left: 0;
}

#slider-arrows .arrow-right {
    float: right;
}

.slide {
    color: #fff;
    background: #494949;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

.heading {
    font-size: 28px;
    padding: 4% 6%;
    display: inline-flex;
}

.heading i {
    padding-right: 10px;
    color: #4991e3;
    font-size: 22px;
}

.num {
    font-size: 14px;
    padding-left: 100px;
}

.first {
    border-bottom: 5px solid #C9C9C9;
}

.radio {
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 22px;
    padding: 4% 6%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
 <div class="container">
     <div class="wrap-slider">
         <form id="form-slider" action="" method="post">
             <div class="slide">
              <div class="heading first">
               <i class="fa fa-file-text-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>

               <p>Пройди тест за 2 минуты, и узнай как удвоить поток клиентов в свой бизенс! Чек-лист по маркетингу стоимостью 20.000 р в подарок</p>

               <div class="num">1/6</div>
              </div>

              <div class="radio">
                  <p>Ваш бизнес продвигается с помощью сети интернет ?</p>
                  <p>
                   <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="answer1" value="answer1">
                   <label for="answer1">&nbsp&nbspДа</label>
                  </p>
                  <p>
                   <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="answer2" value="answer2">
                   <label for="answer2">&nbsp&nbspНет</label>
                  </p>
              </div>
     
     <div id="slider-arrows">
               <!--<div class="arrow-left">Назад</div>-->
               <div class="arrow-right">Вперед</div>
           </div>
             </div>

             <div class="slide">
                 <p>Вопрос 2</p>
                 <p>Ответ <input type="radio" name="radio2" value="answer1"></p>
                 <p>Ответ <input type="radio" name="radio2" value="answer2"></p>
                 <p>Ответ <input type="radio" name="radio2" value="answer3"></p>

     <div id="slider-arrows">
               <div class="arrow-left">Назад</div>
               <div class="arrow-right">Вперед</div>
           </div>
             </div>

             <div class="slide">
                 <p>Вопрос 3</p>
                 <p>Ответ <input type="radio" name="radio3" value="answer1"></p>
                 <p>Ответ <input type="radio" name="radio3" value="answer2"></p>
                 <p>Ответ <input type="radio" name="radio3" value="answer3"></p>
             </div>

             <div class="slide">
                 <p>Конец</p>
                 <p><input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Введите Ваше имя"></p>
                 <p><input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="Введите Ваш номер"></p>
                 <p><input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Введите Ваше мыло"></p>
                 <p><input type="submit" name="save"></p>
             </div>
         </form>
     </div>
 </div>
</section>
```